# Handle location popups in EDGE and Safari using selenium java

Tags: java, selenium, safari, geolocation, microsoft-edge

I am trying to handle location popups in selenium java for multiple browsers. I am not able to find out the solution for MS Edge and Safari. I am trying to achieve the same as below for these browser:

```
                FirefoxProfile geoDisabled = new FirefoxProfile();
                geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.enabled", false);
                geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.provider.use_corelocation", false);
                geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing", true);
                geoDisabled.setPreference("geo.prompt.testing.allow", true);
                caps.setCapability(FirefoxDriver.PROFILE,geoDisabled);
```

or in Chrome as :

```
               ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();

                // SET CHROME OPTIONS
                // 0 - Default, 1 - Allow, 2 - Block
                int locationFlag = location.equals(true) ? 1:2;

                Map< String, Object > prefs = new HashMap<>();
                Map < String, Object > profile = new HashMap <> ();
                Map < String, Object > contentSettings = new HashMap <> ();
                contentSettings.put("geolocation", locationFlag);
                profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentSettings);
                prefs.put("profile", profile);
                chromeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
```

**Update:**
Following solution worked for MSEdge:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
                if(isPrivate) {
                    edgeOptions.addArguments("inprivate");
                }
                int locationFlag = location.equals(true) ? 1:2;
                Map< String, Object > prefs = new HashMap<>();
                Map < String, Object > profile = new HashMap <> ();
                Map < String, Object > contentSettings = new HashMap <> ();
                contentSettings.put("geolocation", locationFlag);
                profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentSettings);
                prefs.put("profile", profile);
                edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
                caps.merge(edgeOptions);
```

There is still no progress on Safari.

Comment: Chrome and Edge are both Chromium based browsers, you can try similar code, or try setting these capabilities in `ms:edgeOptions` to see if it works. For more details, please refer to this doc: [EdgeOptions Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/capabilities-edge-options#edgeoptions-object).

Comment: @XudongPeng, Thanks alot. It works. Now only safari remains.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. If possible, you can post your solution as an answer and mark it as answer. This will help other community members with similar issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @XudongPeng - I am waiting for an answer for Safari.. I have updated the Edge solution in my question as an update though.

Answer (score 0):

For edge:

```
EdgeOptions edgeOptions = new EdgeOptions();
                if(isPrivate) {
                    edgeOptions.addArguments("inprivate");
                }
                int locationFlag = location.equals(true) ? 1:2;
                Map< String, Object > prefs = new HashMap<>();
                Map < String, Object > profile = new HashMap <> ();
                Map < String, Object > contentSettings = new HashMap <> ();
                contentSettings.put("geolocation", locationFlag);
                profile.put("managed_default_content_settings", contentSettings);
                prefs.put("profile", profile);
                edgeOptions.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
                caps.merge(edgeOptions);
```

Safari doesn't support as of now to manipulate location prefs.